# Import CSV into Salesforce (group edition) automatically

Tags: csv, salesforce

I'd like to import CSV file into Salesforce automatically, e.g. once a day. I can't use Data Loader (Bulk API), because I don't have the needed edition. Is there any other, simple way?

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if DBAmp (on the app exchange) is available for your edition. If it is, then you can use a SQL stored procedure to do it.

Otherwise, I think your only other option would be to schedule an Apex job in Salesforce to grab it from somewhere accessible (like an FTP).

Comment: DBAmp is a pretty expensive solution - The company could rather buy higher edition (but that's what I want to avoid). Apex job is also impossible - it's not supported by group edition.

Comment: Sorry. I think you may be screwed then. Dbamp isn't cheap but it's definitely one of the cheaper apps on the exchange. If they are non profit they can probably get a discount.